# Azure CDN - Enabling HTTP 304 Caching with ETag - Hosted Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, http-compression, http-caching, azure-cdn

We are trying to enable **HTTP compression** (gzip) and **HTTP 304 Caching** via ETags on Azure CDN. We already discovered an issue with [enabling Azure CDN Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10434390/175679), but now we can't get compression and ETag caching ([304s](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5)) working simultaneously. This issue has been [posted to Azure forums here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/e16a3017-651b-41a7-af2a-d0b0ae1cfe1b).

#### [Here is an example of the compressed](http://bit.ly/Lfb6c8), but not HTTP cacheable (304) link:

> https://xxxx.vo.msecnd.net/resourceManager.axd?token=HL80vX5hf3lIAAA&group=core.js

#### [Here is an example of the cacheable (304)](http://bit.ly/KR3b24), but not compressible (gzip) link:

> https://xxxx.vo.msecnd.net/resourceManager.axd?token=HL80vX5hf3lIAAA&group=core.png

Does anyone know how to get **HTTP Caching (304s)** and **HTTP Compression** working together on the Azure CDN?

Comment: I am working on it to get some traction from Windows Azure CDN team. I will provide an answer as soon as I get more info. Meanwhile would u please example what do you mean by "HTTP 304 Caching via Etags"?

Comment: I think we know what is going on however I need some more info in order to investigate our side. Would u please send your  Azure CDN endpoint (az######.vo.msecnd.net) details?

Comment: @Avkash - see links above (*e.g. Here is an example of...*). Our current endpoint is **az194054.vo.msecnd.net**

Comment: See [this link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) regarding HTTP 304 usage. Essentially, we assign the ETag in the origin and subsequent requests from the CDN should serve up 304s (*if the eTag is the same*) instead of 200s to reduce bandwidth requirements. See [this MSDN post relating to Azure Blob Storage and eTag support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179371.aspx). We are counting on the **If-None-Match** request header sending back 304 responses from the CDN.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As of now we are investigating this our side usign the info provided and I will get back as soon as we make some progress. Also one thing to note: png files aren’t compressible. I don’t know what you think you are getting back from that request for “core.,png”, but it’s not a gzip’d PNG file. Have u checked it?

Comment: One more question: Are you specifying If-None-Match or If-Match? Based on my experience, most users rely on modification date and GET If-Modified-Since.

Comment: @Avkash - you just found our workaround! You should post this as a solution. [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3889533/175679) has a good comparison of **ETag/In-None-Match** vs. **Last Modified/If-Modified-Since**. It seems ETag is stronger if you need to a cache flag for a given entity with multiple encodings, etc. For our purposes, Last **Modified/If-Modified-Since** works good enough, we don't need variable caching based off encodings. You rock - please add this as the answer. We've verified using HTTP Header **Last Modified** 304s as desired.

Comment: Wow.. I am glad it worked out for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to know if you are specifying **If-None-Match** or **If-Match**? Based on my experience, most users rely on **modification date** and GET **If-Modified-Since**.

**ETag** is stronger if you need to a cache flag for a given entity with multiple encodings, etc.

For your requirement please use **Modified/If-Modified-Since** and you don't need variable caching based off encodings and this should work.

More info is here: [HttpWebResponse LastModified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887622/httpwebresponse-lastmodified/3889533#3889533)

Comment: Thanks for your help - this would have been a show-stopper for us!