# Default Value for HttpWebResponse.LastModified

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebresponse

As documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.lastmodified(v=vs.110).aspx) the LastModified property of the HttpWebResponse class:

> contains the value of the Last-Modified header received with the
>   response

Per a few other answers on here and other pages online ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887638/1742551) for example):

> It's completely up to the server if it sets the Last-Modified
>   response header

If the server does not set this header, what should I expect the value of the property to be in .Net? DateTime.MinValue? DateTime.Now? Or is there some other way to detect if the server set this header?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` probably

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I've added to my question - if that's the case, how can I tell the difference between the server sending me a LastModified of DateTime.Now, and .Net detecting a missing header and defaulting the property to DateTime.Now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of [HttpWebResponse](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs,280) you will see, that `DateTime.Now` is returned, if no Last-Modified header has been set by the server.

In order to determine, if a header value is present in the reponse, you can use the [HttpWebResponse.GetResponseHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponseheader(v=vs.110).aspx) method. E.g.

```
var isLastModifiedSent = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(webResponse.GetResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
```